# Totalling a variable in OCaml

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, ocaml, ml

I have a program which loops through a string and prints out the `dir` of each character.

I want to total these `dir` values up into a single discrete value, which I can print.

Here is my current code:

```
let word = "(())";;

let dir = function
  | '(' -> 1
  | ')' -> -1
  | _ -> 0;;

let z =
  (String.iter (fun (c: char) ->
    let d = dir c in
      Printf.printf "%d is the direction of %c\n" d c
  ) word);;
```

At the moment, this prints out the following:

```
1 is the direction of (
1 is the direction of (
-1 is the direction of )
-1 is the direction of )
```

Instead of printing these out, I would like it to sum the 4 values (1, 1, -1, -1) and print out:

```
The overall direction is 0
```

How can I achieve this in OCaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops in OCaml as well as other functional programming languages are usually expressed using recursive functions. Here is a possible implementation:

```
let count_parens str =
  let n = String.length str in
  let rec loop s i =
    if i < n then match str.[i] with
      | '(' -> loop (s + 1) (i + 1)
      | ')' -> loop (s - 1) (i + 1)
      | _ -> loop s (i + 1)
    else s in
  loop 0 0
```

Or, using your `dir` function:

```
let count_parens str =
  let n = String.length str in
  let rec loop s i =
    if i < n then loop (s + dir str.[i]) (i + 1)
    else s in
  loop 0 0
```

A reification of  a loop is a `fold` function. Unfortunately there is no `String.fold` function in the OCaml standard library. But you can use a [`Core`](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel) standard library produces by Janestreet. With `fold` function this loop can be expressed more concise:

```
open Core_kernel.Std  

let count_parens str =
  String.fold str ~init:0 ~f:(fun s c -> s + dir c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should use `fold` instead of `iter`. Since there's no `fold` in the standard String library, you might have to write your own.

A slightly longer answer is that you probably want to write a recursive function that tracks a cumulative sum as one of its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using a reference :

```
let z =
  let counter = ref 0 in (String.iter (fun (c: char) ->
    counter := (!counter + dir c)
  ) word); !counter;;
```

Comment: Using references here is counter-idiomatic. It obscures loop variants and introduces other caveats of imperative programming. Also, this is a functional programming language, so it is better to use functional approach, whenever it is possible. And you don't  need to use so many parentheses, they only clutter the code.

Comment: Initially I wanted to use sth like String.fold and not use reference. On the other side, even if references should be avoided in functional programming for the reason you mention, in the current case it makes the code shorter.